# After installation of github plugin into jenkins, restart not responding and showing errors

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Even I remove the github plugin from jenkins not working. which is running under the tomcat7 server.

```
hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad:  org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/config.xml
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:237)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/config.xml
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:269)
at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:44)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:914)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:813)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:83)
at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:79)
at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:225)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/config.xml
at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:165)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$16.run(Jenkins.java:2642)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:903)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you see a Java stack trace, you can usually find what the problem is by looking at the "Caused by:" line.  Here is yours:

```
Caused by: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /usr/share/tomcat7/.jenkins/config.xml
```

Jenkins is unable to read its configuration file.  This could be due to one of:

- The file doesn't exist
- The file isn't readable by the user that runs the Jenkins process (note that it needs to be writable as well)
- The JENKINS_HOME environment variable isn't set correctly for the user that runs the Jenkins process

Comment: You're making a presumption here. I get a similar erorr, and the config.xml file definitely DOES exist, with proper permissions. The error is related to a plugin that was installed

Comment: @vikingsteve why not add details of your error so that others can benefit from your experience, instead of just downvoting an answer that is perfectly valid in other cases ?

Comment: The error related to a plugin that was a dependency of another plugin being badly installed (junit plugin in my case). Although it *seemed* like it could not read config.xml (or that config.xml didn't exist, or had bad permissions), this wasn't the case. I had to edit config.xml and restart jenkins *without* security, resolve the plugin issues manually, and then restart it *with* security.